# Add wildcard to RegEx for phrases and text matching

Tags: c#, regex, datatable, wildcard

I have a text file which consists of:

1. stemmed words (e.g. manipulat - stemmed from "manipulating"), and
2. stemmed phrases which are usually two words or more (e.g.
   "acknowledg him regard the invest" - stemmed from "acknowledging him
   regarding the investment").

Each word/phrase is presented in a new line. My C# code reads each line in this text file, then for each line, search all rows in the DataTable to match them. i.e. if a word/phrase appears in any rows of DataTable, my system will flag the row..

For single word, it's easily done/matched using the algorithm I have. I can match "manipulat" to words like "manipulate", "manipulating", "manipulated" and "manipulation" if they appear in the DataTable rows.

But for phrases, my algorithm can only match exactly what it is. Here I mean if my phrase is "acknowledg him regard the invest", it will only search for the exact phrase, and it won't match/flag if "acknowledging him regarding the investment" exists in DataTable rows.

I have very little knowledge in both Regex and C#. I tried to modify the below code to use wildcards but no luck so far. Would appreciate if anyone can help in this. Thank you in advanced.

```
string[] words = File.ReadAllLines(sourceDirTemp + comboBox_filename.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".txt");
        var query = LoadComments().AsEnumerable().Where(r =>
            words.Any(wordOrPhrase => Regex.IsMatch(r.Field<string>("Column_name"), @"\b" 
                + Regex.Escape(wordOrPhrase) + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)));
```

Comment: if you can change the database values you could change the phrases to be regex patterns, i.e. `acknowledg him regard the invest` becomes `acknowledg[a-z]* him regard[a-z]* the invest[a-z]*`.

Comment: There is a problem: if you just split the `wordOrPhrase` with spaces, and add `\w*` to each, you could match `himself` with `him` (that would be turned into `him\w*`. What is your plan on this?

Comment: Anyway, what I suggest is `Regex.IsMatch(r.Field<string>("Column_name"), string.Join(" +", 
   wordOrPhrase.Split().Select(p => string.Format(@"\b{0}\w*\b", Regex.Escape(p)))), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

Answer (score 0):

When comparing the lines with the stem-words from your database using 
`RegEx` you could extend your pattern in your code.

This will match 1 or more occurrences of any word character

```
\w+
```

This will match 0 or more occurrences of any word character

```
\w*
```

as Abbodanza already mentioned this will match any character between **a** and **z** 0 or more occurrences.

```
[a-z]*
```

EDIT:

If your algorithm works for single words you could split each phrase

```
string[] words = File.ReadAllLines(sourceDirTemp + comboBox_filename.SelectedItem.ToString();
foreach(var word in words)
{
    // moreOrOneWord.Length would allow you to check whether it is a phrase
    string [] moreOrOneWord = words.Split(' ');

    var query = LoadComments().AsEnumerable().Where(r =>
            moreOrOneWord.Any(wordOrPhrase => Regex.IsMatch(r.Field<string>("Column_name"), @"\b" 
                + Regex.Escape(wordOrPhrase) + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)));

    // Do something with the query...

}
```

This should allow you to apply your algorithm to every single word in the text.

[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx) you can find an example to start with regular expression.

and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) is a List of RegEx elements that you can use.

Hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

If you split the `wordOrPhrase` with space, and add `\w*` to match 0+ alphanumeric or underscore chars (or more specific pattern to only match letters like `[\p{L}\p{M}]*`) to each chunk, you could use

```
Regex.IsMatch(r.Field<string>("Column_name"), 
    string.Join(" +", wordOrPhrase.Split()
        .Select(p => string.Format(@"\b{0}\w*\b", Regex.Escape(p)))),
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

If you have a `acknowledg him regard the invest` *wordOrPhrase*, the regex will be `\backnowledg\w*\b +\bhim\w*\b +\bregard\w*\b +\bthe\w*\b +\binvest\w*\b` and will find a match. See [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Dws5T2).

However, with this approach, `himself` will get matched with `him` (that would be turned into `him\w*`).